# Write a Object List into a CSV file format

Tags: vb.net, csv

So I have a list of Object that I want to write into a CSV file format to export so that the user can save various config to import later. I don't really want to reinvent the wheel if anyone has done this already.

I have searched online, but I only found examples for datatables?

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do the Objects have a useful string representation?

Comment: Anything wrong with converting to a DataTable and then using the approach you found?

Comment: Yup the object does have a string representation. Nothing wrong with a datatable, seems like its pretty useless as I dont have database or anything. Im looking for a way to do it directly.

Comment: You could serialize/deserialize into an XML file.

Comment: It's really only a half dozen lines or so.  Open a StreamWriter, iterate over Objects and call WriteLine, close the StreamWriter.  The wheel is very small...